# How to colourise user input in IDLE's terminal?

Tags: python, python-idle

How do I change the text input in  IDLE's terminal to green?

```
import sys

try:
    color = sys.stdout.shell
except AttributeError:
    raise RuntimeError("Use IDLE")

full_name = input('What is your name?')

color.write("My name is ","DEFINITION")
color.write(full_name,"DEFINITION")
```

Answer (score 0):

On the Highlights tab of the Options dialog, one can define colors separately for "Normal Code or Text" and "Shell User Output".  The former includes both  shell code input at the '>>>' prompt and responses to input() prompts.  (That input() responses get syntax colorized is a low-priority but that I will eventual fix.)

I am not sure what you want to do, but one cannot currently define user colors from user code.  The only influence is whether one sends output to sys.stdout or sys.stderr.